# Updating a plugin in Monaca

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, monaca

I'm developing a custom plugin for myself to use in Monaca. I added the plugin to my project and built it with some errors. Afterwards I changed some code and pushed the plugin to github. I deleted the plugin from Monaca and installed it again, but Monaca still seems to build the old version of the plugin, since it gives the same errors regarding the erroneous plugin code.

How can I make sure Monaca updates the sources inside the platform folder accordingly, whenever I add or remove a plugin?

Thanks.

Comment: can you please write the procedure you followed when you updated the plugin?

Answer (score -1):

"pushed the plugin to github" you mean it is the import edited plugin to Monaca project?

I think you're using Monaca Debugger. If so try rebuild your Monaca debugger and reinstall debugger to device.

Custom Plugin will come included inside Monaca Debugger.